# Deploy eclipse product to maven repository

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

How can I deploy materialized product to Nexus repository? Everything I read seems to show how to publish individual artifacts.

Comment: Is your product a multi-module maven project, or individual projects?

Comment: What is a "materialized product"?

Comment: @Andre Yes, a multi-module maven project

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen A compressed Eclipse product that is build using tycho-p2-director-plugin's materialize-products goal. it's a zip file for instance, that contains Eclipse platform plugins and our plugins. Everything I've read and from what I've tried seems to deploy artifacts of individual maven projects, but not collection of them.